# Getting logged out after Page reload several times

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sometimes I get logged out after refreshing page, I'm not exactly what could be wrong because all I do every page load is check if user is authenticated with forms authentication and if a variable session is null

```
 if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["Nome"] == null)
{
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

and this is my webconfig file, I set expire time for 300 minutes so i don't understand...

```
<configuration>

<system.web>    
<customErrors mode="Off"/>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/Account/Inicio.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="300" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="300" cookieless="false"></sessionState>

<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<!-- MAXIMO TAMANHO DE UPLOAD POR FICHEIRO-->
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="5242880"/>
<identity impersonate="false"/>
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="Login.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>



<handlers>
    <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" 
      path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>

</system.webServer>

<appSettings>

   <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
 </appSettings>
 <runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">


  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

and this is my login

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Login_Txt.Text;
        string password = Pass_Txt.Text;
        bool rememberMe = false;

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            int IdUser = Security.ValidateLogin(username, password);
            //int IdUser = 4;
            switch (IdUser)
            {
                case -1:
                    Label_Erro.Text = "Username/Password incorrecto.";
                    break;
                default:
                    var user = Utilizador.GetUserData(IdUser);                            
                    Session["Nome"] = user.Nome;                        

                    // Create a new FormsAuthenticationTicket that includes our User Data
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, IdUser.ToString(), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(300), rememberMe, user.Grupo, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                    string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
                    // check if it exists, if not then redirect to default page
                    if (returnUrl == null) returnUrl = "~/Account/Inicio.aspx";
                    Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Sometimes" is not a sufficient for us for trying to help you. Sometimes could be also one time in a timelaps greater than 300 minutes

Comment: Well hard to understand what is going on here cause I always set expiration time  and I'm hoping someone had the same problem and managed to solve it